# difference between methods of registering JDBC drivers

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle9i, oracle-adf

method1:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

This is the most common approach that use Java's Class.forName( ) method to dynamically load the driver's class file into memory, 
which automatically registers it.

---

method2:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
```

This approach is to use a combination of Class.forName( ) to dynamically load the 
Oracle driver and then the driver classes' getInstance( ) method to work around 
noncompliant JVMs, but then you'll have to code for two extra Exceptions.

Is there any specific difference between these two approach? i am not getting this second method

thanks

Comment: source from where i read is : Java Programming with Oracle JDBC,Donald Bales,Publisher: O'Reilly

Comment: Neither of those should be necessary with a JDBC 4.0 compliant driver because of the automatic driver registration introduced Java5

Comment: See here: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/10/whats-new-in-jdbc-40.html#getting-connected-becomes-easier